# How to filter within a date range using UCanAccess library

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

Trying to query records which fall between a date range, upon executing query, Java console throws a 'UCAExc:::4.0.4 unknown token: '
It does not show the token

through trial and error I found that the error lies between the library comprehending the date range of the query,

```
String sql = reportMaster.getQuery();
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
           ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

This already works when directly executing in Microsoft Access and should produce 3 fields, instead it throws unknown token error in java  console
EDIT:

i tested the original query(Below) in chunks to see if there was a syntax error, the records can be filtered by status and a SINGLE date but does not accept a date range

the SQL statement is:

```
SELECT ID from event
WHERE status = 'Offline' AND (event_date >= #01/09/2017# AND event_date <= #21/04/2018#)
```

Comment: And the SQL is?

Comment: Apologies, the SQL is:
SELECT ID from event WHERE status = 'Offline' AND (event_date >= #01/09/2017# AND event_date <= #21/04/2018#)

Comment: Note that Access will generate incorrect results, even if this would work. Access interprets dates as mm/dd/yyyy, but in the absence of a 21st month, Access will interpret the first date as the 9th of january and the second date as the 21st of april. This is probably not what you intend.

Comment: Try specifying the date literals as unambiguous `#yyyy-mm-dd#` values using hyphens as the separators.

Comment: Except for the format of the date expressions (as already noted), your syntax is correct. So, something else is going on.

Comment: @GordThompson Perfect!!! that worked thanks! :)